# Substitution inside inline markup while escaping whitespace

Tags: python, substitution, restructuredtext

Given the following reST document

```
.. |bar| replace:: baz

bolded? :strong:`\ |bar|\ `

bolded? **\ |bar|**

.. This one errors out
.. bolded? **\ |bar|\ **
```

How do I create a bolded, substituted value? I want

> bolded? **baz**

Here's a link to the online editor to test it out: http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=f57ac95e1fe1643572b45d7ae8f8950c&theme=basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reStructuredText doesn't support nested inline markup, the only way to create a reference with styled text is to use substitutions with the "replace" directive

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replacement-text