# Version Substitution is not working in sub documents

Tags: python-sphinx, versioning, substitution, restructuredtext

We are using Sphinx to create user manuals for our clients. Now every time we release a new version we need to update the version number of the new release consistently throughout the manual.

For this it seems advisable to use the predefined `|version|` substitution.

**index.rst**

```
User manual
#######################

*Product |version|* can be used to ... 

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :numbered:

   tutorial
```

**tutorial.rst**

```
Tutorial
############

We are glad, that you are using *Product |version|*!
```

Now, the generated HTML code correctly replaces the `|version|` tag in the `index.rst`, but unfortunately there is no replacement in the `tutorial.rst`.

Does anyone knows what goes wrong here?

Comment: I would not expect `*Product |version|*` to work. That is nested inline markup, which is not supported. It should work if you remove the asterisks.

Comment: @mzjn: Many thanks, you are right. Any workaround, if I really need `*Product |version|*`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33537747/407651